# How to calculate the time difference (duration) in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt

I use xlstproc to transform some xml file to another xml format file, during transformation, I need to calculate the time difference value (durations in seconds or minutes:seconds) between start and end fields.

`...
    <start>2011-12-13 16:15:26</start>
    <end>2011-12-13 16:17:27</end>
...`

I found a Template Syntax, but failed to make use of it.

```
<xsl:call-template name="date:duration">
  <xsl:with-param name="seconds" select="number" />?
</xsl:call-template>
```

Would appreciate somebody can give me a hint how to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a Template Syntax". You mean you found a template that was supposed to calculate the time difference between two time strings? In any case, if you show or link to the template implementation, and **describe how it failed to work**, we can probably help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some of your work for you and found [this date:duration function](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/duration/index.html), which you seem to be trying to use. However, date:duration converts a number of seconds into a duration formatted string, whereas you want to find the difference (duration) between two datetime strings.

You probably want [date:difference](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/date.difference.template.xsl) instead.
If you read the [documentation for this function/template](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html), you'll find this about the arguments:

> The two dates must both be right-truncated date/time strings in one of
>   the formats defined in [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes]. ... The permitted formats are as follows...
>
> ```
> xs:dateTime (CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss)
> ...
> ```

There are italics there in the original: *CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss* except the T is not italicized. In other words, the time strings need a literal `T` between the date and the time, whereas yours have a space.

So I would suggest fixing that:

```
<start>2011-12-13T16:15:26</start>
  <end>2011-12-13T16:17:27</end>
```

Pass the `start` and `end` strings as parameters to the template. You can do this by just passing the `start` and `end` element nodes, which will be automatically converted to strings based on their text content:

```
<xsl:variable name="time-diff-dur">
  <xsl:call-template name="date:difference">
    <xsl:with-param name="start" select="start" />
    <xsl:with-param name="end" select="end" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<!-- The above returns a duration formatted string, so convert that to seconds: -->
<xsl:variable name="time-diff-sec">
  <xsl:call-template name="date:seconds">
    <xsl:with-param name="seconds" select="$time-diff-dur" />?
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

This code assumes that the context node is the parent of the `<start>` and `<end>` elements. After the above code, the variable `$time-diff-sec` will contain a result tree fragment, which can be converted to a number using `number($time-diff-sec)` if necessary.

Let us know whether that works. If not, state specifically **what the result was** and how it differs from what you expected.

### Update:

I just noticed that you are using xsltproc (which uses libxslt). According to [this documentation](http://www.exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html), libxslt supports `date:difference` (and `date:seconds`) natively. So you can call these functions as functions instead of defining a named template and calling it as a template. That would be a lot less code for you, albeit less portable:

```
<xsl:variable name="time-diff-sec"
    select="date:seconds(date:difference(start, end))" />
```

As before, you will need to declare the `date` namespace prefix somewhere, usually on your `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="date">
```

### Update 2:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604414/finding-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-xslt) for a portable XSLT 1.0 template to convert a date string to number of seconds, which allows you to easily subtract one date from another. (Thanks to Sam B for that comment).

Comment: It works with the suggestion within update section, thanks a lot!

Comment: @KarlboZino, you're welcome. Glad it helped. Please check the checkmark to "accept" the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Another Perfect answser - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604414/finding-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-xslt