# Finding the difference in MS between two dateTimes in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file which includes some dates with start and end points, like shown as follows:

```
<events>
    <event>
        <start time="2018-10-20T10:11:36.465Z"/>
        <end time="2018-10-20T09:33:04.349Z"/>
    </event>
</events>
```

How to calculate the difference between these two date in millisecond (MS) ?

I find something here from michael.hor257k : [Finding the difference between two dateTimes in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604414/finding-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-xslt) 
but unfortunately, my level is too bad to re-use this one :(

Comment: What processor do you use? If it supports exslt (http://exslt.org/date/functions/difference/index.html), you might be able to use the date:difference function.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doen't support exslt :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="event">
    <xsl:variable name="start">
        <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
            <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="start/@time" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:variable name="end">
        <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
            <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="end/@time" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="duration" select="$end - $start" />

                <duration>
                               <xsl:value-of select="$duration"/>
                </duration>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>

    <xsl:variable name="datetmp" select="substring-before($dateTime, 'Z')" />

    <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($datetmp, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-after($datetmp, 'T')" />

    <xsl:variable name="local-time" select="substring($time, 1, string-length($time) - 4)" />

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)" />

    <xsl:variable name="hour" select="substring($local-time, 1, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="minute" select="substring($local-time, 4, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="second" select="substring($local-time, 7)" />
    <xsl:variable name="millis" select="substring-after(substring-after($time, $local-time),'.')" />

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="jd" select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />

    <xsl:value-of select="((86400*$jd + 3600*$hour + 60*$minute + $second) * 1000) + $millis " />
</xsl:template> 


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a good man from my work, a good man :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="event">
        <xsl:variable name="start">
            <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="start/@time" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable> 

        <xsl:variable name="end">
            <xsl:call-template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="end/@time" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="duration" select="$start - $end" />


        <duration>
            <xsl:value-of select="$duration"/>
        </duration>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dateTime-to-seconds">
        <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>

        <xsl:variable name="datetmp" select="substring-before($dateTime, 'Z')" />

        <xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($datetmp, 'T')" />
        <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-after($datetmp, 'T')" />

        <xsl:variable name="local-time" select="substring($time, 1, string-length($time) - 4)" />

        <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)" />

        <xsl:variable name="hour" select="substring($local-time, 1, 2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="minute" select="substring($local-time, 4, 2)" />
        <xsl:variable name="second" select="substring($local-time, 7)" />
        <xsl:variable name="millis" select="substring-after(substring-after($time, $local-time),'.')" />

        <xsl:variable name="yearms" select="$year * 31556900000" />
        <xsl:variable name="months" select="$month * 2629740000" />
        <xsl:variable name="dayms" select="$day * 86400000" />
        <xsl:variable name="hrms" select="$hour * 3600000" />
        <xsl:variable name="minms" select="$minute * 60000" />
        <xsl:variable name="secms" select="$second * 1000" />


        <xsl:value-of select="$yearms + $months + $dayms + $hrms + $minms + $secms + $millis " />
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo : http://xsltransform.net/jxWYjVm/2

Comment: You seem to think that all years have exactly the same duration, and likewise all months - which everyone knows is not true.