# How to get number of secondes between two dates with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wso2-esb

I am working with WSO2 ESB and i would like to know how can i get secondes betwenn date A and B.
Basically, i would like to calcul time between system time and 12.00pm.
Do you have any idea ? I found how to do get number of days but nothing for secondes with Xpath only.
I am restricted with Xpath because i can't use a Java script.

Thank you.

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604414/finding-the-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-xslt If not, add more details.

Comment: It gave me some interesting functions but not what i am looking for. Thank you for your time, Ophychius found what i was looking for

Comment: This answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/38607378/3016153 is identical to the one you have accepted here.

Comment: Ophychius answer is more understandable for me, sorry if my question is a duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic is to turn both into proper xs:dateTime objects, then calculate the difference. This will give you a dayTimeDuration. Divide this by the dayTimeDuration of 1 second and you have your difference in seconds. Example:

```
<property xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="now" 
expression="concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'T',get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'HH:mm:ss')) "/>
<property xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="12pm" 
expression="concat(get-property('SYSTEM_DATE', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'T12:00:00')"/>


<property xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="diff" 
expression="xs:dayTimeDuration(xs:dateTime(syn:get-property('now'))-xs:dateTime(syn:get-property('12pm'))) div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
```

Keep in mind you need to enable xpath 2.0 for this on the ESB/EI. You can do this by uncommenting the following line in your [WSO2CARBON_HOM]/repository/conf/synapse.properties file.

```
#synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true
```

Also keep in mind that once you have done that, xpath expression where you combine functions from synapse namespace (like get-property) with normal xpath functions will require the use of a prefix like in the code example.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you !