# Find out the difference between two date times using xslt or xquery

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery

I am new to xslt and xquery . can someone please guide me with below:

I want to find out the difference in two date times is less than 24 hours by using xslt 1.0 or xquery

For example: In response I receive `2022-03-10T10:57:53.746-05:00`
I want to compare it with current datetime and make sure it is less than 24 hours

Comment: XQuery in any version, if I am not mistaken, should have support for `xs:dateTime` and arithmetics e.g. `current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('2022-03-10T10:57:53.746-05:00')` gives you a duration

Comment: For XSLT 1.0 solution see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38615456/3016153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Martin's comment, a pure XPath 2 version (meaning [compatible with XSLT 2 and all XQuery](https://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-functions/)) is:

```
current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('2022-03-10T10:57:53.746-05:00') 
  lt xs:dayTimeDuration("PT24H")
```

This is in case you weren't sure how to express the "less than 24 hours" condition. (An equivalent duration would be `P1D`.)

But this expression isn't compatible with XSLT 1.0. For that, [the link to the XSLT 1.0 solution from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441366/find-out-the-difference-between-two-date-times-using-xslt-or-xquery#comment126274455_71441366) would be required.