# Xslt or Xquery to test the time difference less than hours

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery

I am new to xquery and xslt. So i was able to get the time difference in a variable in this format by using `fn:current-datetime- xs:datetime()`.
The output is `P11DT2H2M20.404S`
But now my question is: Is there any function to calculate the Hours are less than 24 hours or how can I get find out its less than 24 hours?

I can use substring after T and then compare with 24 hours but wanted to know if there is a better way.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 does not have a native way to return the current date or time. Some processors support this as extension - so we need to know which processor you are using in order  to give you an XSLT answer.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441366/find-out-the-difference-between-two-date-times-using-xslt-or-xquery ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide one duration by another e.g. `xs:dayTimeDuration('P11DT2H2M20.404S') div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT24H')` divides by 24 hours and if that result is less than 1 than the (original) duration is less than 24 hours.

Comment: @Simran, see the answer by Michael Kay, I overlooked the comparison operators being defined on durations so you do not even need to divide the durations, you can just compare them.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
`if ($myDuration lt xs:dayTimeDuration('PT24H')) ...`
```

which seems more direct than Martin's solution.